# Spark Structured streaming(batch mode) - running dependent jobs concurrently

Tags: google-cloud-platform, concurrency, python-asyncio, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I've a Structured Streaming program running on GCP Dataproc cluster which reads data from Kafka every 10 mins, and then does processing.
This is a multi-tenant system i.e. the program will read data from multiple customers.

In my current code, i'm looping over the customers passing it to the 3 programs - P1, P2, P3
P1, P2, P3 are  classes where the bulk of the processing happens, and the data is pushed back to kafka

```
def convertToDictForEachBatch(df, batchId):

    # code to change syslog to required format - this is not  included here since it is not relevant to the issue
    
    # loop over the customers, and call the classes P1, P2, P3 for each customer
    # TBD : run the processes in aynchronous fashion/concurrently
    for cust in hm.values():
    
            # tdict_ap - has data specific to P2, filter code is not shown
            p1 = P1(tdict_ap, spark, False, cust)
            
            
            # tdict_ap - has data specific to P2, filter code is not shown
            p2 = P2(tdict_ap, spark, False, cust)
            
            
            # tdict_ap - has data specific to P3, filter code is not shown
            p3 = P3(tdict_ap, spark, False, cust)
            
            
                

# df_stream = data read from Kafka, this calls function convertToDictForEachBatch       

query = df_stream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp", "topic").writeStream \
         .outputMode("append") \
         .trigger(processingTime='10 minutes') \
         .option("truncate", "false") \
         .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint) \
         .foreachBatch(convertToDictForEachBatch) \
         .start()
```

In the above code, the processing is sequential .. I would like to make the processing concurrent/asynchronous to the extent possible

Couple of options I'm considering :

1. Using asyncio
   - from what i understand, this might improve the performance since for each customer - it might allow processing in 3 classes in asynchronous fashion
2. 

use repartition data dataframe by 'customer' + groupBy
- this should allow concurrency for the multiple customers (in a specific class) if there are sufficient executors

Here is the same code for this,
I think this might need to be done in each of the 3 classes P1, P2, P3

```
window = Window.partitionBy('cust')

all_DF = all_DF.repartition('cust').cache()

results = (
    all_DF
    .groupBy('cust')
    .apply(<function>)
    )
```

Pls advise on what is the best way to achieve this ?

tia!

Comment: Can you run several program in parallel in your cluster? Each one take in parameter the customer to process

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - the code reads data from all sys.* topics, and derives the customer name from the topic .. this way we can avoid any manual intervention when new customer is onboarded .. if we have to start  a new job for each new customer onboarded, that would require manual intervention and setup .. something i would like to avoid. Hope that clarifies!